# Error making a up / down action loop under IF condition

Tags: autohotkey

I have attempted to make a script where the Gui controler once the checkbox selected it would toggle the specific key that is associated to it.

I was successful at adding IF Ab = 1 send {a down} then under adding an else to review the state of the key to make it go up after 100ms so that it could loop. However i want to do a loop of going forward then backwards ( These keys are as W for forward and S for backwards ) unfortunately i have been unsuccessful.

Without adding everything of the code... here are the important bits.

```
TTshowing = 0
Gui, -Caption +LastFound +AlwaysOnTop
Gui, Add, Checkbox, gRefocus cWhite, Y
Gui, Add, Checkbox, gRefocus cWhite, S
Gui, Add, Checkbox, gRefocus cWhite, U
Gui, Add, Checkbox, gRefocus cWhite, I
Gui, Add, Checkbox, gRefocus cWhite, O
Gui, Add, Checkbox, gRefocus cWhite, M
```

```
Loop
{
   GuiControlGet, Yb, , Button1
   GuiControlGet, Sb, , Button2
   GuiControlGet, Ub, , Button3
   GuiControlGet, Ib, , Button4
   GuiControlGet, Ob, , Button5
   GuiControlGet, Mb, , Button6
   if Yb = 1
      Send y
   if Sb = 1
      Send {s down}
   if Ub = 1
      Send u
   if Ib = 1
      Send I
   if Ob = 1
      Send O
   if Mb = 1
        GetKeyState, keyWstate, W
        if %keyWstate% = up
        Send {w down}
        Sleep 600
        GetKeyState, keyWstate, W
        if %keyWstate% = down
        Send {w up}
        Sleep 100   
        GetKeyState, keySstate, S
        if %keySstate% = up
        Send {s down}
        Sleep 650
        GetKeyState, keySstate, S
        if %keySstate% = down
        Send {s up}
        Sleep 100}
}
Return
```

This would allow to go up / down, I also tried to have Send{w down} Sleep 600 { send etc.. doesn't work just takes the last send, same goes for delay action etc.

The current code where it allows for either Up or down but not both is this one that I modified :

```
Loop
{
   GuiControlGet, Yb, , Button1
   GuiControlGet, Sb, , Button2
   GuiControlGet, Ub, , Button3
   GuiControlGet, Ib, , Button4
   GuiControlGet, Ob, , Button5
   GuiControlGet, Mb, , Button6
   if Yb = 1
      Send y
   if Ub = 1
      Send u
   if Ib = 1
      Send I
   if Ob = 1
      Send O
   if Sb = 1
      Send {S down}
   if Mb = 1
      Send {W down}
   else
   GetKeyState, keySstate, S
   if %keySstate% = down
      Send {s up}
   Sleep 100
   GetKeyState, keyWstate, W
   if %keyWstate% = down
      Send {w up}
   Sleep 100
}
Return
```

Original code was by someone else and I modified it with success however to make this loop, I also attempted to create a secondary loop, no success either.

What I'd like to do is to have under If Mb = 1

To have the system to press down on S for 1000ms then press up then to press w for 1000ms then to press up and loop so that It can simply go back and forth indefinitely.

EDIT ::: Answer found ::: Thanks for the help.

```
Loop
{
   GuiControlGet, Yb, , Button1
   GuiControlGet, Ub, , Button2
   GuiControlGet, Ib, , Button3
   GuiControlGet, Ob, , Button4
   GuiControlGet, Sb, , Button5
   GuiControlGet, Wb, , Button6
   GuiControlGet, Tb, , Button7
   if Yb = 1
      Send y
   if Ub = 1
      Send u
   if Ib = 1
      Send I
   if Ob = 1
      Send O
   if Tb = 1
      Send {TAB}
   if Sb = 1
      Send {S down}
    Sleep 500
   GetKeyState, state, S
   if state = D
      Send {S up}
   Sleep 50
   if Wb = 1
      Send {W down}
   Sleep 500
   GetKeyState, state, W
   if state = "D"
      Send {W up}
   Sleep 50
}
Return
```

Changing the code from a statename to simply state facilitates the communication, also Up and down are variables and they are not known only U or D can be used in getstate. Therefore modifing these by adding them right after the initial key stroke and removing the else resolved it, therefore now it goes back and forth. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there might be a couple issues with your code. GetKeyState stores "D", "U", or nothing in the output variable and not the whole words 'up' or 'down'. The other issue has to do with the syntax of the IF-statement. In your case, you'll want to have it something like this: `If keySstate = "D"`.

Also, you mentioned wanting to hold for 1000ms; however, your code is set for 100ms.

This is not an error, but you may want to consider using the GetKeyState() function instead. That way you can combine it with your IF-statement; something like, `If GetKeyState( "s" )`.

https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/GetKeyState.htm

Please update your code with the mentioned corrections and we can go from there if there are still issues.

Comment: The reason `if Sb = 1 Send {S down}` works is because 1 is a value. If you don't enclose strings in quotes, it will treat it as a variable - a variable that has no value stored in it.

Comment: Unfortunately that is not the case, As the previous code shows the following
```   
if Sb = 1
      Send {S down}
```
Therefore if the checkbox "S" on the screen is ticked ( checked ) As it is (state 1 ) Therefore it sends {S down} this presses the key S down.
If both S and W are checked they are both pressed... I tried with what you said as D and U however  S down and W down works fine, just the way it reacts that is the problem.

I appreciate your answer and it made me think of doing it another way, adding a secondary loop within the same GUI controler ill keep you updated.

Comment: Oh Ok ok, i see what you mean therefore it should be KeySstate, "S"

I will try this, however what i will do is change the "sleep" 400 and 800 accordingly see if there is movement first and if it worked.

Comment: Yes, just for the if-statement though.

Comment: That fixed it, Edited the code and that was the issue, I have to change a bit the timing of it but otherwise it works like a charm! Thanks for pointing it out much appreciated.I will add the code in the initial post as edit.